# Partially Matches for search result in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

In the above pic i have to search the sap code from sheet 2  to the respective..
By Taking some words like  Master/13 or visa/chennai we have match the sapcode from sheet 2.. 
[image]

```
srchString = "visa/20160927/Chennai/FT"
Set rng = Worksheets("Rulebook_Temp").Cells.find(what:=srchString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)
```

Its returning empty for me...

Comment: You don't have the `visa/20160927/Chennai/FT` string on your cells... So probably you are getting a runtime error, right?

Comment: If you want to search _part_ of a string, then only _supply part_ of the string, e.g. `"visa/20160927/"` Or simply use a [vlookup with a wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910579/can-you-use-wildcards-with-vlookup)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is to remove the date part of the card type in your source and destination and then you could do a simple lookup. If you have a string like `a/b/c/d` in cell `A1`, this will return `a/c/d`

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))>2,REPLACE(A1,FIND("/",A1),FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1)+1)-FIND("/",A1),""),A1)
```

It also checks to make sure that there are more than 2 `/`, so in the case of `a/b` the value will be left unchanged. This therefore also works with your `premium/007` value

Comment: Its the above formula is used to eliminate date from the text.what i want is in the above code i have two visa card with different location with different sap id...ie i wanna to return visa/chennai  means sap008 and visa/bangalore means sap031

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by iterating through the cells as follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A60")

Dim foundString, delimiterStr As String
Dim object() As String
delimiterStr = "||"
Dim n As Integer
For n = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

If CStr(rng.Cells(n, 1).Text) Like "*visa/20160927/Chennai/FT*" Then

foundString = foundString & CStr(rng.Cells(n, 1).Text) & delimiterStr 

End If
Next n

object = Split(foundString, delimiterStr)

Dim rng_1 As Range

Set rng_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1")

Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(object) To UBound(object)

rng_1.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value = object(i)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: for me error on End If Next n

Comment: The next n should be on a different line

Comment: input_txt = " MASTERCARD /PT/DE/EI/IND-CHN OLA"
      rulebook_sht = "Mastercard CHN" 

If rulebook_sht Like input_txt Then

input_sht.Range("C" & i).Value = rule_sht.Range("C" & j).Value
input_sht.Range("D" & i).Value = rule_sht.Range("D" & j).Value
input_sht.Range("E" & i).Value = rule_sht.Range("E" & j).Value
input_sht.Range("F" & i).Value = rule_sht.Range("F" & j).Value

End If

Comment: the above code is working fine if i compare  input text  as "MASTERCARD /PT/DE/EI/IND-CHN OLA"  and rule = "Master" its works.can anyone help into this

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too
use excel arrays

use this to return the rows that contain the code

IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Master/13",Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50,1)),ROW(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$50))

then use SMALL to return the first row on the sheet 2 where the match was found

SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Master/13",Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50,1)),ROW(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$50)),1)

Then use index to return the value

INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$50,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Master/13",Sheet2!$A$2:$A$50,1)),ROW(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$50)),1))

Enter as an array Control + Shift + Enter

This should work I have tested