# Why is VLookup Inconsistent?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm using a `VLookup` in a spreadsheet and finding really inconsistent results. For example here's are 2 entries from my sheet that's using the VLookup lookup:

```
Date      | Transaction Type             | Description                  | Paid Out | Paid In | Balance | Category
xx-May-xx | ATM Withdrawal BARCLAYS BANK | ATM Withdrawal BARCLAYS BANK | £10.00   |         | £xxx.xx | #N/A
yy-May-yy | ATM Withdrawal NAT WEST      | ATM Withdrawal NAT WEST      | £10.00   |         | £yyy.yy | Cash
```

The forumla I'm using for my lookup references a `CategoryLookup` table, which has a bunch of blank lines (trying to eliminate potential issues) and has the following:

```
Description                  | Category
(blank lines...)
ATM Withdrawal LINK          | Cash                  -- Row 25
ATM Withdrawal               | Cash
ATM Withdrawal BARCLAYS BANK | Cash                  -- Row 27
```

The formula I'm using for my VLookup is as follows: `=VLOOKUP([@Description],CategoryLookup!$A$2:$B$9999,2)`. I can't understand why I'm getting `#N/A` for some of my values. If I replace the blank lines with my previous category lookups then they seem to get returned even though they're no way near the description I'm using for lookup.

Note that unfortunately in this case I need a fuzzy lookup as other categories aren't so exact on the match/

Comment: There is nothing fuzzy about the formula you are using, and it requires the list to be sorted. Is it?

Comment: I thought the last parameter (defaults to true) was a fuzzy search? I hadn't come across the list to be sorted - is that the lookup list based on the Description field?

Comment: The last parameter controls whether vlookup uses [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (fast), which requires the list to be sorted, or naive scan (slow) which does not. The "approximate" from the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is an unfortunate way of saying this, because it makes it sound like it's a fuzzy match, which it's not. It is kind of justified because it will return a value that is close to the sought for value if the list is sorted, but the value is not on it.

Comment: @GSerg hmm, thanks. Not 100% sure it'll do what I want then, but I can give it a try before cracking out some code and regex. Do you want to add an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can you use wildcards with vlookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3911571/11683)

Comment: If you _really_ need a Fuzzy lookup, [try this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=15011)